# Class' has not been declared error when I declared it

Tags: c++, oop

I'm making a little shell that can just do random stuff. Bt whenever i compile i receive the error `'Shell' has not been declared`

I declared the class shell and the object i n main.cpp, i've looked for a while and nothing. I'm new to oop so this may be pretty stupid but i've done wha to know

I'm using 3 files

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shell/shell.cpp"


int main ()
{
 Shell shl;
 while (!shl.exitTime())
 {
     std::cin.ignore();
     shl.putIn(std::getline(std::cin));
 }

}
```

/shell/shell.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include "shell.h"


class Shell {

private:
    std::string in;
    bool exitBool;

public:
    // Functions
    void clear();
    void print(std::string inp);
    void println(std::string inp);
    void putIn(std::string inp);
    std::string input();
    bool exitTime();

Shell()
{
    exitBool = false;
}


};
```

and /shell/shell.h:

```
 #include <vector>


void Shell::print(std::string inp)
{
std::cout << inp;
}

void Shell::println(std::string inp)
{
std::cout << inp << std::endl;
} 

void Shell::putIn(std::string inp)
{
inp = in;
}

std::string Shell::input()
{
return in;
} 

bool exitTime()
{
return exitBool;
}
```

Comment: The contents of shell.h and shell.cpp are the wrong way around.

Comment: It looks like you've got the contents of your `shell.h` and `shell.cpp` backwards... but you have the `#include "shell.h"` correctly in the cpp. But you've incorrectly got `#include "shell.cpp"` in main... This looks like you were copy pasting and flip flopped a couple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

- Write *definitions* of class functions in `.cpp` files.
- Write *declarations* of class functions in `.h` files.
- Include `.h` files.

You actually did

- Write *definitions* of class functions in `.h` files.
- Write *declarations* of class functions in `.cpp` files.
- Include `.cpp` files.

Try this:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shell/shell.h"


int main ()
{
 Shell shl;
 while (!shl.exitTime())
 {
     std::cin.ignore();
     shl.putIn(std::getline(std::cin));
 }

}
```

/shell/shell.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include "shell.h"

void Shell::print(std::string inp)
{
std::cout << inp;
}

void Shell::println(std::string inp)
{
std::cout << inp << std::endl;
} 

void Shell::putIn(std::string inp)
{
inp = in;
}

std::string Shell::input()
{
return in;
} 

bool exitTime()
{
return exitBool;
}
```

and /shell/shell.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Shell {

private:
    std::string in;
    bool exitBool;

public:
    // Functions
    void clear();
    void print(std::string inp);
    void println(std::string inp);
    void putIn(std::string inp);
    std::string input();
    bool exitTime();

Shell()
{
    exitBool = false;
}


};
```

Comment: Side note: `shl.putIn(std::getline(std::cin));` is looking a bit goofy as well. `getline` needs an `istream` and a `string` as parameters .

Comment: The `std::cin.ignore();` is probably going to be a mistake sooner or later as well. `ignore` after an operation that leaves unwanted data in the stream, not before a future operation. If you `ignore` before an operation, sooner or later you hit a case where there is no garbage to be removed and discard data you did want.